# Java sql update row in database

Tags: java, sql, database

I have got adding a member to the database working.
I am trying to work out how to update a row in the table using the same system of passing in the values just not adding a new row, just altering the row using the passed in username.

Here is my method for inserting a new member:

```
 public static void insertMember(String username,String firstName)
{

    try 
     {  
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);

        PreparedStatement st = connection.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO Members VALUES (?,?)");
        st.setString(1, username);
        st.setString(2, firstName);
        st.executeUpdate();    
     } 

     catch (SQLException e) 
     {
        System.out.println("SQL Exception: "+ e.toString());
     } 

     catch (ClassNotFoundException cE) 
     {
        System.out.println("Class Not Found Exception: "+ cE.toString());
     }


}
```

Comment: `INSERT` statement will **insert** rows in a table, while `UPDATE` statement will **update** a row (or a group of rows) in a table.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use an `UPDATE` command instead of `INSERT` command.

Take a look at [SQL UPDATE statement](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_update.asp).

You will need to provide some means by which you can identify the row which needs to be updated, but this is dependent upon the structure of your table

Answer (score 2):

*I have got adding a member to the database working. I am trying to work out how to update a row in the table using the same system of passing in the values just not adding a new row, just altering the row using the passed in username.*

you need `Update` command

like

```
UPDATE Members set username='somename',firstname='firstname' where condition
```

Answer (score 0):

Need to change SQL command instead of INSERT , uses UPDATE. 
Below code will update username for matching firstname provided in where clause.

```
          PreparedStatement st = connection.prepareStatement("UPDATE Members set username=? where firstName=?)");
         st.setString(1, username);
         st.setString(2, firstName);
         int updateStatus=st.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: I guess you should update the first name of the user based on the username, not backwards :).

Comment: Wouldn't that require a `where` statement so you knew which row was to be updated?